# Table with multiple lines in some cells

Tags: tables

What is the easiest way to have 2 lines in some of the cells in a table?

The only way I can think right now is to actually have 2 separate rows (without the line in the middle) and use `\multirow` on all other cells in this row. Any easier ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Maybe post a small complete document with a table that shows what you want. If you use the `p` column type, you can have paragraphs within a table cell.  Will that solve the problem?

Comment: here is an excellent solution: http://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You could nest a `tabular` within another `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  One & Two & Three & Four \\
  Een & Twee & Drie & Vier \\
  One & Two & 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Three \\ Drie\end{tabular}
  & Four
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The use of `@{}..@{}` voids the additional space (horizontal tab separation) inserted by the nested `tabular`.

Also, the above example inserts the nested `tabular` vertically centered with respect to the row. If you want it `t`op or `b`ottom aligned, use the optional parameter to `tabular`: `\begin{tabular}[t]..` or `\begin{tabular}[b]...`.

Note that this approach also works within math mode for an `array`.

Comment: The result is really beautiful.

Comment: How to center the content inside this tabular?

Comment: @PaulRBerg: I'm not sure I understand your question. All the content in the `tabular` is `c`entred based on the column specification.

Comment: Oh right! Sorry, I had my own implementation and I missed the `c` in your answer. It's working now, thanks.

Comment: This answer actually cope quite well with whole table scaling (using `\tiny`, for example).

Answer (score 168):

When using a [`p`-type column](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#The_tabular_environment), one can set the width of a column:

> By default, if the text in a column is too wide for the page, LaTeX won’t automatically wrap it. Using p{'width'} you can define a special type of column which will wrap-around the text as in a normal paragraph. You can pass the width using any unit supported by LaTeX, such as 'pt' and 'cm'...

The `p` column does not only allow text to be automatically broken in multiple lines depending on the size of the column as given, it also allows for the use of `\newline` in the tabular environment:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|p{15mm}}
  \hline
  foo & bar \newline rlz \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Which gives:
[image: example of p-type column]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It would be good to emphasise this requires a `p` type column

Comment: `\newline` works without any issues in tabularx.

Comment: I thought I could use `p{\textwidth}` to get automatic column width adjustment. Alas does not work. It then uses a column width of the text without the `\newline`.

Comment: I prefer [Wolfone's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501507/178369). Using `makecell` allows to control the line break and vertically centers text in other columns.

Comment: Will this always result in left-justification or is it possible to center the text?

Comment: (Just to complete Nagabhushan's comment) makecell in fact gives you options to decide vertical and horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 93):

The easiest way is to use `\shortstack` but it is not very flexible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    one & two & three \\
    one & two & \shortstack{aa \\ bb}\\

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

`\shortstack` takes an option to align content left `[l]`, right `[r]`, or center `[c]`(default). 
Another idea is to use `\parbox[t]{5cm}{aa\\bb}` because it provides options to align the lines vertically.

Comment: I prefer [Wolfone's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501507/178369). Using `makecell` vertically centers text in other columns.

Comment: (Just to complete Nagabhushan's comment), makecell gives you options to decide vertical and horizontal alignment.

Comment: This is probably the one you're after if you have a little bit of extra text that you want to wrap, rather than have it stretch out the column width

Comment: I believe @NagabhushanSN is correct. Otherwise, the rest of the columns in the table will align with the last line in your multirow column which doesn't quite look right in my opinion

Answer (score 58):

Another possible solution — my preferred one in my use-cases so far as I wanted full control to what comes in which line while being as concise as possible — is using the [`makecell`](https://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package, which would make it possible to have multi-line cells via:

```latex
\usepackage{makecell}

...

\begin{tabular}{lll}
    & some & information & more &\\
    & info & \makecell{ line1 \\ line2 }  &  blubb &\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Make sure to include `\usepackage{makecell}` to make this work.

Comment: For alignment of text inside makecell, use `\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}`. The first argument(c here) is for horizontal alignment and the second argument is for vertical alignment.

Comment: You may want to use this instead to left align the content of makecell `\makecell[l]{content}`

Answer (score 9):

here are some cell definitions that i've used to good effect in situations where the content of table cells was essentially text:

```
\newcommand{\lcell}[2][1.2in]{%
  $\vcenter{\hsize#1\baselineskip11pt\vspace*{3pt}\raggedright#2\strut\par}$}
\newcommand{\slcell}[2][1.2in]{%
  $\vcenter{\hsize#1\baselineskip9.5pt\vspace*{3pt}\raggedright#2\strut\par}$}
\newcommand{\ccell}[2][.42in]{%
  $\vcenter{\hsize#1\baselineskip11pt\vspace*{3pt}\centering#2\strut\par}$}
```

the job(s) involved had `\usepackage{array}` to get the augmented facilities.

of course, the dimensions were specific to the job, and would need to be changed depending on the circumstances; and fine tuning was definitely needed in the actual jobs involved.  type was assumed to be 10pt for `\lcell` and `\ccell` or 8pt for `\slcell`; i also `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}` to keep the tops of cell content from crashing into lines above, and the `\strut` assures consistent clearance below.

line breaks in cells were usually manual (though they needn't be), with `\break`, and if a continuation line should be indented in a left-aligned cell, an `\hspace*` would be needed.  the `\par` at the end ensures that the specified baseline is observed.

to me, multi-line text content of cells looks much better with "normal" text baseline settings than it does with the usual table row separation.

for table headings, vertical centering of multiple lines doesn't look so good; they look better aligned at the bottom.  here's the definition i used for that:

```
\newcommand{\thead}[2][.75in]{%
  \vbox{\hsize#1\baselineskip11pt\centering\vspace*{3pt}#2\par}}
```

some of these headings ran to four or more lines (complicated headings above narrow columns of numbers).  the results were actually quite respectable.

Answer (score 7):

You can also put minipages in your cells. Its especially interesting if you have a whole text in a cell and you want it to make linebreaks by its own.

e.g.

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
\begin{minipage}{5mm} ~\\ foo \\ bar \\ \end{minipage} & foo \\ \hline
foo & bar \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX! Your answer seems good to me, however you could maybe expand it a little or provide an example to make it more efficient. Do not forget to "quote" an already existing answer if you referred to it create yours.

Comment: Remark: it may be better to just leave a newline instead of ``\\``: [paragraphs - When to use \par and when \\\\, \newline, or blank lines - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

Why Not partition your text into two rows just donot put the hline between the rows, something like this:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
A & B &C\\
D & E &F\\
\hline
G & H & I\\
\hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Comment: It's more work than a `\shortstack` for example. In general it will result in a lot of `&`.

Comment: and it is not flexible. What if you want to change the order of rows or columns after creating the table?

Answer (score 5):

It’s easy peasy with `tblr` environment of the new LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={clr},hlines}
    one & {left\\leftttt} & three          \\
    one & two             & {right\\rightttt} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The array function works like a charm. I have extra functions in here that are not necessary for answering the above question such as the \resizebox - needed to fit all my words on the pdf page, \begin{figure} - I want the table centered with a caption and I know putting the table in a figure will do this, \bullet just makes a bullet for a list, \textrm just makes text non-italic while in math mode (i.e. while in between $ $). copy and paste in texmaker, it works.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
Methods & Pros & Cons\\
\hline
Anharmonic DC SQUID & $\begin{array}{l}
\bullet \textrm{ Fast readout} \\ 
\bullet \textrm{ Accessible equipment}
\end{array}$ & 
$\begin{array}{l}
\bullet \textrm{ Large currents} \\ 
\bullet \textrm{ Requires knowledge of other junction}\\
\bullet \textrm{ Not decoupled from apparatus}
\end{array}$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A nested `tabular` with `\textbullet` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a preference as to exactly what text will go on the second line or the third line, this is the best option:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{2cm}p{2cm}p{2cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}}

\end{tabular}
```

Only reason I am answering this is because I faced a similar problem (where I didn't have a preference) and it worked wonders.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain better why this will solve the given issue ...