# Formatting table with multiple items in cells in one column

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a question that is very similar to this: [How to use itemize in Table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150492/how-to-use-itemize-in-table-environment) and [Table with multiple lines in some cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells)
However, instead of the content of the table being written directly in latex, it is for a big table that is being read in as xml output from R. For one column of the content, there are multiple entries (separated by a semi-colon) that I'd like to show as bullet points in one cell, for all elements in that column.
Any ideas? I was thinking something with multirow{} or a tabular within the table, but I don't think these options work when the data is read in as an external format.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: You would need some tool or other to generate LaTeX markup from your XML. It would seem more straightforward though to let R generate LaTeX directly? There seem to be R backends for that, although I haven't used them and don't know how to customize them at the level of detail you have in mind.

Comment: Without a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) it's difficult to say but it sounds like you might profit from looking at either the [cvssimple](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cvssimple) or [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\small}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{O}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{| M{3cm} | N{3cm} | O{3cm} | P{3cm} |}

\hline
TITLE 1 & TITLE 2 & TITLE 3 & TITLE 4\\

\hline
Some content here &
Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\\
\hline

\hline
Some content here\newline Some content here &
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here\\
\hline

\hline
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here &
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here\\
\hline

\hline
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here &
Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here & 
Some content here\newline Some content here\newline Some content here\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for your answer. Could you add some [explanations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)?