# how to create a nested table

Tags: tables, tabularx, nesting

I searched how to create a nested table but I didn't find a solution that works for me.
What I need is to create this table.

[image]

Any one can help please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX, please show us, what you've got so far. A compilable example would be the best, not just a picture. Have a look here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells shows several ways to do it.

Comment: Where would you have a nested table?

Comment: @Bernard each module can has many scenarios.
For each scenarios I have ID + scenarios  + priority

Comment: Must I understand the scenario with highest priority has a blue background, and it does not necessarily follow the scheme ‘each other subrow has a blue background’?

Comment: @Bernard Don't focus on color background.
I used it to seperate between rows.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried, so we don't have to type everything from scratch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, your table example is more a merge/span of several rows from the column "ID scénario" than a nested table. In Excel, which seems to be your original model, this would be the equivalent of merge.

For documentation, [this page](https://texblog.org/2012/12/21/multi-column-and-multi-row-cells-in-latex-tables/) provides an example, using the [multirow](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package, under the section "Multiple rows". Let me know if you need a full example, I'll add it here below.

Bonne chance, Xavier

### Edit 1 - Example 1

And here it is, this produce a similar table, with the first 2 columns being merges by rows, according to your example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabulary}
% \usepackage{polyglossia}
% \setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|c|l|l|L|L|}
    \hline
    ID Module & Module & ID Scenario & Scenario & Priorite \\
    \hline
    1 & Gestion de l'inscription & 1.1 & En tant que & Elevee \\    
    \hline  
    \multirow{2}{*}{2} & \multirow{2}{*}{Gestion de l'inscription} & 2.1 & En tant que & Elevee \\
    & & 2.2 & En tant que & Elevee \\   
    \hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, if possible I need a full example.

Comment: the tabluraly influenced the width of subsections and subsubsections title.
Is there a way to reset the title width

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without `multirow`, using the `tabularx` environmen, and a slightly different layout with `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, french]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ tabularx, makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering\sffamily
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries\color{white}}
\rowcolors{3}{white}{AliceBlue}
\arrayrulewidth = 0.8pt
\arrayrulecolor{SkyBlue}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|>{\RaggedRight\hsize=0.75\hsize}X|c|>{\RaggedRight\hsize=1.25\hsize}X|l|}
    \hline
 \rowcolor{SteelBlue} \thead{ID\\ Module} & \thead{Module} & \thead{ID\\ Scénario} & \thead{Scénario} & \thead{Priorité}\\
    \hline
    1 & Gestion de l'inscription & 1.1 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je peux créer un compte pour accéder à l’application & Élevée \\
    \hline
    2 & Gestion d’authentification & 2.1 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je peux m’authentifier pour accéder à mon compte& Élevée \\
\cellcolor{white} & \cellcolor{white}& 2.2 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je peux m’authentifier pour accéder à mon compte & Élevée \\
 \hline
3 & Gestion des comptes & 3.1 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je veux gérer les utilisateurs de la plate-forme & Élevée \\
 \cellcolor{white} & \cellcolor{white}& 3.2 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je veux gérer mon compte & Élevée \\
 \hline
 4 & Gestion des produits & 4.1 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je veux con\-sulter les produits de Marketplace & Élevée \\
 \cellcolor{white} & \cellcolor{white} & 4.2 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je veux modifier les produits de Marketplace & Élevée \\
   & &4.3 & En tant qu’utilisateur, je veux supprimer les produits de Marketplace & Élevée \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]