# Easy way to line-break specific table cells

Tags: tables, parbox, textwidth

I have a table with long text and found a way to get rid of the issue where one has to do line-breaks manually. Here is the code for a very simple version of this layout:

```
\usepackage{booktabs} % for toprule, midrule and bottomrule

\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \toprule
    Category & Description \\
    \midrule
    \parbox[t]{.10\textwidth}{A} & \parbox[t]{.90\textwidth}{PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table that adapts}
\end{table*}
```

I often create tables that have this general format: two columns that expand over the full text width of the page and that divide into two parts (like here, 10-90, but also adapted based on the size of the text in the first column).

Is there a way to turn this into a command (or is there perhap already a command) so that I do not have to write the parbox for every cell?

Also, it would be nice to simplify this so that I only have to declare the size of one cell (10%) to define the remainder (90%) implicitly for all cells.

Any ideas how to do this efficiently?

Comment: Please note that this will give you an overfull box as the available space for the two columns is not a full `\textwidth` but a `\textwidth-4\tabcolsep` (`2\tabcolsep` per column), if you add vertical lines and the `array` package is loaded each vertical line takes an additional `\arrayrulewidth`.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [Table with multiple lines in some cells - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells). The `\newline` solution is covered there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ordinary `p` type columns and use `\newline` instead of `\\` to introduce a manual line break in the cell:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for toprule, midrule and bottomrule

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ p{.1\textwidth} p{\dimexpr.9\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax} }
    \toprule
    Category & Description \\
    \midrule
    A & PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\newline PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A table that adapts}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions based on `tabularx`, one with fixed column widths ratio (had to be changed by trial and error with the default margins to 1:7), another with the `l` column specifier for the first column.

Note that in the first solution with the relative column widths ratio, the sum of the coefficients of `\hsize` have to be equal to the total number of `X` columns.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for toprule, midrule and bottomrule

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[! htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\hsize=0.25\hsize}X>{\hsize=1.75\hsize\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    Category & Description \\
    \midrule
    A & PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\newline PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table that adapts}
\end{table*}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{table*}[!htb]
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\arraybackslash}X}
    \toprule
    Category & Description \\
    \midrule
    A & PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\newline PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE. PUT DESCRIPTION HERE.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{A table that adapts}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that while setting the relative widths this way one must pay attention to make sure the total used multiples of `\hsize` match the number of `X` type columns. It is also advised to set `\linewidth=\hsize` in the preamble.

Comment: @Skillmon: I've updated my answer for the first point.For your second point, why is it advised? I didn't see it in the documentation,  never used it  and had no problem. Are there special situations where it could be problematic?

Comment: From `tabularx` documentation, section 4.3: "`{>{\hsize=.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X
>{\hsize=1.5\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}`" (end of citation). One might use code inside of a column which depends on the `\linewidth` instead of the `\hsize`.