# Tables to present equations and their elements

Tags: tables

I'm trying to present a equation in this way

[image: Example of Table]

I don't know if it's the best way to present this information, but i got that example from a reference guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suspect that you looking for the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]
    \[\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{r c >{$}r<{$:} l}
\multirow[t]{3}{*}{$
Q_r=\dfrac{W}{\gamma\times t}
                  $}    & where & W         & Weight \\
                        &       & \gamma    & Specific weight\\
                        &       & t         & Average time
\end{tabular}
    \]
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was looking for. Can you elaborate on what does `\[\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}`?

Comment: `\[` and `]` are delimiters for math environment (equivalent for `\begin{equation*}` and `\end{equation}`. with `\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}` is added vertical space of 1pt above cells' contents. you can omit this space, if you like to have more dense text in `tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses a single `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\begin{document}
\[
Q_r=\frac{W}{\gamma\times t} \qquad\text{where}\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{@{} r<{\colon} L @{}}
   W      & Weight \\
   \gamma & Specific weight\\
   t      & Average time
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells) and got this

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
$Q_r=\dfrac{W}{\gamma \times t}$& where & \begin{tabular}{rl}
&\\
&\\
$W$:&Weight\\
$\gamma$:&Specific weight\\
$t$:&Average time
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But this creates a space *above* the table. I could add a `\vspace{-0.5cm}` before the table.

Comment: The reason for the whitespace above the `tabular` environment is that the `tabular` environment comprises 5 rather than just 3 rows, with the first two rows being left empty. Assuming you wanted to keep using nested `tabular` environments, the best way to get rid of the unwanted whitespace is to replace both instances of `\begin{tabular}` with `\begin{tabular}[t]`, i.e., to require top-alignment, and to get rid of the two blank rows. Do note that you don't actually need the "outer" `tabular` environment. Just encase formula and its legend in a display-math environment.