# Working with long table in landscape orientation

Tags: longtable, page-numbering, multicolumn, landscape

Admitted I handle thing poorly when it comes to working with table.

In my report I reached a point that I want to insert table (landscape) that would span multiple pages. So I used `\longtable`.

Formatting is the challenge:

1. columns containing list poorly  displayed
2. had to use `\multicolumn` repeatedly to adjust cells on several rows
3. page number is poorly placed.

Below is a MWE of the problem I faced.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lclll }
\toprule
            \thead{Algorithm}  & \thead{Type of Problem} & \thead{Advantages}  & \thead{Disadvantages}  & \thead{Common Application areas} \\
            \midrule
 Decision Trees &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{supervised/unsupervised} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{
 \begin{itemize}
     \item robust to outliers and missing values
     \item item 2
     \item item 3
 \end{itemize}} &list advantages & some application areas\\
 \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding the column formatting, you may find some interesting options in the answers to a question entitled [Table with multiple lines in some cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40561/182363), in particular, using [p-type columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102986/182363) and/or [minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142754/182363).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). In addition, I have defined a column that get rid of the space above the itemise environment by injecting a `\@minipagetrue` *and* align the cells at the top base line by enclosing the `itemize` environment in a `\parbox`. As a bonus(?), I could remove the `\thead`-commands and all `\multicolumn`s:

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\@minipagetrue}p{\dimexpr(3.2cm+2\tabcolsep)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lcPll@{}}
\toprule
   \bfseries Algorithm  & \bfseries Type of Problem & \bfseries Advantages  & \bfseries Disadvantages  & \bfseries Common Application areas \\
   \midrule
 Decision Trees &  supervised/unsupervised & \parbox[t]{3.2cm}{\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]
     \item robust to outliers and missing values
     \item item 2
     \item item 3
 \end{itemize}} &list advantages & some application areas\\
 \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\@minipagetrue}p{\dimexpr(4.5cm+2\tabcolsep)}}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}lOPll@{}}
\toprule
   \bfseries Algorithm  & \bfseries Type of Problem & \bfseries Advantages  & \bfseries Disadvantages  & \bfseries Common Application areas \\
   \midrule
 Decision Trees &  supervised/ unsupervised & \parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt,topsep=0pt, leftmargin=*]

     \item robust to outliers and missing values
     \item item 2
     \item item 3
 \end{itemize}} &list advantages & some application areas\\
 \midrule
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this solution works on first attempt. How do I adjust the width of Advantage column? Column in the middle.

Comment: @arilwan Change the width in the definition of the P-column (3.2 cm) _and_ in the `\parbox`. Those two numbers has to be equal. However, 3.2 cm is maximum width before you get `overfull hbox ` warnings. If you prefer a wider column, you need to shorten other columns. For example, column two can be converted to a p-column and the cell content broken into two lines.

Comment: @arilwan I have included a new example how to manipulate the column width. If you were able to use xltabular, you could have used X-column instead of p-column, and the columns would have adapted automatically.

Comment: Thank you all, you have been of great help. I go fro Example 2.

Comment: @arilwan I discovered that you may set the width of the `\parbox` to `\linewidth` inside the table, and it will adapt to the column width.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution, based on a redefinition of `tabularx`, the `xltabular` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable  to`tabularx`, and`enumitem`. It is far from perfect, athe first two column heads are not vertically aligned, for a reason I don't see.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable, xltabular}
\usepackage{ragged2e, enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\blindtext
\newpage
\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\setlist[itemize]{wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, before =\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}lc *{3}{X}@{}}
\toprule
            \thead{Algorithm} & \thead{Type of Problem} & \thead[l]{Advantages} & \thead[l]{Disadvantages}
             & \thead{Common Application\\ areas } \\
            \midrule
 Decision Trees & \multicolumn{1}{c}{supervised/unsupervised} &
 \begin{itemize}
     \item robust to outliers and missing values
     \item item 2
     \item item 3
 \end{itemize}
 &list advantages & some application areas\\
 \midrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do I format the page number, as you can see from your answer, it is showing as on  portrait orientation.

Comment: Yesz, but that is normal: it is just a convention the reader has to turn the page to read very wide tables, but he/she reads the table, not the page number, nor the headers.

Comment: One more thing please, I run into issues with `xltabular` package, using overleaf :! `LaTeX Error: File xltabular.sty not found. Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed, or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)`

Comment: Overleaf does not have this package installed? It's a comparatively recent package (2 years or so), but that is strange… In this case, you can try loading the `ltablex` package (`xltabular` is built on this one) and replace the  `xltabular` environment with `tabularx`. It might be useful to add the `keepXColumns` directive.

Comment: Ah, I think it's conflicting with other packages I used already. I have some table before using `\usepackage{tabulary}`and `\usepackage{tabularx}` I messed up things, ah! You solution did  work on new project.

Comment: For tabulary, I don't know, bur for tabularx, there should be no problem since it loads it  via `ltablex`.