# Column Alignment For Table

Tags: tables, alignment

I am trying to align column 1 row 1 and column 2 row 1 better (independently) (specifically the Time and seconds, x and also the height and feet, y.  You can see each is off center a bit. I am unable to figure out how to center them better.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Tabular Example}
\author{nbennett }
\date{June 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Table}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\vtop{\hbox{\strut Time}\hbox{\strut (seconds), \(x\)}}&\vtop{\hbox{\strut Height}\hbox{\strut (feet), \(y\)}}\\
\hline
0&8 \\ \hline
0.5 & 20 \\ \hline
1   & 24 \\ \hline
1.5 & 20 \\ \hline
2   & 8 \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure why you say they are off centre? the headings are the widest entry so centering, left, or right aligment are the same. But why the tex primitve code rather than use latex???

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to align? The `c` option will automatically center each cell content. Can you post a description of what you want? Also: use of `\vtop` and `\strut`... probably not the best idea.

Comment: I am wondering if the word Time and seconds x can be more centered and also height and feet, y @Miyase

Comment: @NickB Centered how? Horizontally? It should be automatic, but your use of `\vtop` and `\strut` prevents it.

Comment: You have put them  in a primitive `\hbox` so it will not be centered within the vbox, but the vbox as a whole is centred in the column

Comment: is there a better way to line break the row in tabular?  I tried searching earlier

Comment: Use a `p` -type column (for example).

Comment: nesed tabular or p column, or simply use two rows of the table

Comment: I just tried a couple of things. If you don't like having the headers on a single line (for which column type `c` works wonder, no need for TeX primitives), then David Carlisle's suggestion of using two rows looks the best to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly: you don't want the header on a single line (perhaps because it'd be too wide?) and you want it horizontally centered. Here's something that's very close to your second attempt, but a bit cleaner.

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec={cc}, vlines, hline{1,3-8}, rowsep=0pt}
Time & Height\\
(seconds), $x$ & (feet), $y$\\
0   &  8 \\
0.5 & 20 \\
1   & 24 \\
1.5 & 20 \\
2   & 8 \\
\end{tblr}
```

[image: result]

Comment: thank you for taking the time to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I came up with.  Alignment is better.

```
\begin{tblr}{colspec={|c|c|c|},hlines}
    {Time \\ (seconds), \(x\)} & {Height\\(feet),\(y\)}           \\
    0.5 & 20 \\
1   & 24 \\ 
1.5 & 20 \\
2   & 8 \\ 
\end{tblr}
```

Found the code from another post

[Table with multiple lines in some cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells)

[image]

Comment: If all you want is to have the header horizontally centered and on two lines, using two rows as suggested above is both cleaner and simpler. I'll post some code in a minute.

Comment: In my opinion, this method is better than using two rows. You can replace the argument of `tblr` with `colspec={cc}, hlines, vlines` and `tabularray` will automatically create the correct lines. This is easier and more flexible than @Miyase solution.