# Typesetting two lines of text in rows of a table

Tags: tables

I have a table in which I want rows to have two lines of text. In the first row, I would like "Number of pairs" centered over "of newborn bunnies." In the second row, I would like "January 1" aligned against the left edge of the table and below the date, I would like "Start" indented `3mm` from the left edge. (I put a "%" in front of the first two lines of code so that the code for the table would compile.)

I would also appreciate a suggestion for putting the title within the boundaries of the table.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{stackengine}\setstackEOL{\cr} %EOL is abbreviation for "end of line."
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}



\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\belowbaseline[-7pt]{\stackunder{\bfseries\Longstack{Fibonacci's Rabbit Population\cr Explosion}}{%
\begin{tabular}{|| c | S[table-format=-1.0] | S[table-format=-1.0] | S[table-format=-1.0] ||} \hline
%&Number of pairs\cr of newborn bunnies&{Number of pairs\cr of mature rabbits}&{Total number\cr of pairs of rabbits} \\ \Xhline{0.8pt}
%{January 1\cr \hspace{3mm}Start}&1&0&1 \\ \hline
February 1&0&1&1 \\ \hline
March 1&1&1&2 \\ \hline
April 1&1&2&3 \\ \hline
May 1&2&3&5 \\ \hline
June 1&3&5&8 \\ \hline
July 1&5&8&13 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}}
\hspace{\fill}



\end{document}
```

Comment: [Table with multiple lines in some cells - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40561/table-with-multiple-lines-in-some-cells) first.

Comment: Side note, `\cr` is some TeX primitive, better not using it...?

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

[image]

**Edit:**
As I understood your problem, you like to have multiline text in cells in columns of type `c` and `l` )or in `r`. In such a case is handy to use `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath}     % not needed in this MWE
%\usepackage{amsfonts}    % not needed in this MWE
%\usepackage{stackengine} % not needed in this MWE
%\usepackage{adjustbox}   % not needed in this MWE

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
{\bfseries  
 Fibonacci's Rabbit Population Explosion
 }
 
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|| l | S|S|S[table-format=2.0] ||}
    \hline
    & {\makecell{Number of pairs\\ of newborn bunnies}}
        & {\makecell{Number of pairs\\ of mature rabbits}}
            & {\makecell{Total number\\ of pairs of rabbits}}   \\ 
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\makecell[l]{January 1\\ \quad Start}
            & 1 & 0 &  1    \\ \hline
February 1  & 0 & 1 &  1    \\ \hline
March 1     & 1 & 1 &  2    \\ \hline
April 1     & 1 & 2 &  3    \\ \hline
May 1       & 2 & 3 &  5    \\ \hline
June 1      & 3 & 5 &  8    \\ \hline
July 1      & 5 & 8 & 13    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}


\bigskip
    \begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\sisetup{table-column-width=4em,
         table-format=1.0}
{\bfseries
 Fibonacci's Rabbit\\ Population Explosion
 }

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|| l | S|S|S[table-format=2.0] ||}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Number of pairs of}    \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & {\makecell{newborn\\ bunnies}}
        & {\makecell{mature\\ rabbits}}
            & {\makecell{Total}}       \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\makecell[l]{January 1\\ \quad Start}
            & 1 & 0 &  1    \\ \hline
February 1  & 0 & 1 &  1    \\ \hline
March 1     & 1 & 1 &  2    \\ \hline
April 1     & 1 & 2 &  3    \\ \hline
May 1       & 2 & 3 &  5    \\ \hline
June 1      & 3 & 5 &  8    \\ \hline
July 1      & 5 & 8 & 13    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, in the both examples you can use for columns with numbers `p{<width>` type of columns, where text is automatically broken into two lines.

For example, the second table version you can write as:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
{\bfseries
 Fibonacci's Rabbit Population Explosion
 }

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|| l | *{3}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{4em}|} |}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c||}{Number of pairs of}    \\
    \cline{2-4}
    & newborn bunnies 
        &  mature rabbits 
            &  Total        \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\makecell[l]{January 1\\ \quad Start}
            & 1 & 0 &  1    \\ \hline
February 1  & 0 & 1 &  1    \\ \hline
March 1     & 1 & 1 &  2    \\ \hline
April 1     & 1 & 2 &  3    \\ \hline
May 1       & 2 & 3 &  5    \\ \hline
June 1      & 3 & 5 &  8    \\ \hline
July 1      & 5 & 8 & 13    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In your table with the `\multicolumn{`, you have the commands `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` and `\sisetup{table-column-width=4em, table-format=1.0}{\bfseries Fibonacci's Rabbit\\ Population Explosion}` before the `tabular` environment, but you don't have these in the first `tabular` environment. The widths of the rows in the two tables look the same to me, though. Is `2pt` too small to be noticeable? What is "sisetup," and what is the difference between "table-format=1.0" and table-format=2.0"?

Comment: @user143462, first table use default values of `S` columns but the second has defined them. It has in `sisetup` defined common features for `S` columns, i.e. column width by `table-column-width=4em` and `table-format=1.0` (numbers in column have only one digit integers) which is at last column overwitted by local setting `table-format=2.0`  (two digit integers, zero decimals). I don't see any reason why the text *Fibonacci's Rabbit Population Explosion* should be inside tabular or inside some box. As is written in answer gives nice result at simpler code.

Comment: @user143462, in answer are shown two possible solution. You should use one of them, which you more liked. Both solved your problem, how you can write two line cell content in cels of type `c`, `l˛` and `r`. Beside showed possibilities of course exist other too. For example using `p{width}` column type ca automatically broke text into more lines.

Comment: @user143462, see edited answer.

Comment: I appreciate the options that you bothered to typeset. I will use the first one, but I like the other two.

Comment: What is the difference between using the option `l` and the option `S[table-format = 2.0]`? What does the `2.0` signify? I looked on stackexchange for a description of this option and did find any. The only options with which I am familiar is `l`, `r`, and `c`.